# Language hotkeys get removed on reboot in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, language, hotkeys

I have more than 2 languages, so I find it comfortable to work when the hotkeys are specified in the following way:

- English - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
- German - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
- Swedish - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

On Windows reboot the settings disappear each time.

OS Info: Windows 10 64-bit, version 1803, OS Build 17134.48

For some reason Windows 7 & 8 don't have this problem.

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have found a workaround, which handles the issue perfectly.

1. Download this free utility https://autohotkey.com
2. Create *.ahk file and paste the script

```
    ; This should be replaced by whatever your native language is. See 
    ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    ; for the language identifiers list.

    en := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", "00000409", "Int", 1)
    de := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", "00000C07", "Int", 1)
    sv := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", "0000081D", "Int", 1)

    ^1::
    w := DllCall("GetForegroundWindow")
    pid := DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "UInt", w, "Ptr", 0)
    l := DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", pid)
    PostMessage 0x50, 0, %en%,, A
    return

    ^2::
    w := DllCall("GetForegroundWindow")
    pid := DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "UInt", w, "Ptr", 0)
    l := DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", pid)
    PostMessage 0x50, 0, %de%,, A
    return

    ^3::
    w := DllCall("GetForegroundWindow")
    pid := DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "UInt", w, "Ptr", 0)
    l := DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", pid)
    PostMessage 0x50, 0, %sv%,, A
    return
```

Please note, that we define language in the following way:

```
sv := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", "0000081D", "Int", 1)
```

The language identifier for Swedish according to website mentioned in the script is

```
0x081D
```

which means we only take the last 3 characters

```
81D
```

and prefix them with 5 zeroes e.g.

```
0000081D
```

3. After that you create an *.exe file using the aforementioned application
4. Put the executable to Windows 10 autostart folder

press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type

```
shell:startup
```

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you see the folder - that's it!